# HTML Agility pack create new HTMLNode

Tags: html, parsing, indexing, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to parse and transform a HTML file, but I get an exception "Item has already been added" when try to create a new HTMLNode because of the index parameter.

```
HtmlNode node1 = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, 0); 
node1.Name = "div"; 

HtmlNode node2 = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, 0); 
node2.Name = "div";
```

Comment: Could you also paste a piece of your .NET code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how you can create a node (it basically mimics System.Xml semantics, on purpose):

```
    HtmlNode div = doc.CreateElement("div");
    myNode.Append(div);
```

I don't know about this constructor you use, maybe a new one available in version 1.4?