# Inserting new node in html document in c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to insert new node in the document using htmlagilitypack. I am reading the document from the stream , insert the node and then return the document as a FileContentResult object :

```
HtmlDocument ndoc = new HtmlDocument();
ndoc.Load(stream);

HtmlNode usern = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img .... />");
usern.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.location.href='/Home/Index';");
ndoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("id('main')").AppendChild(usern);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   ndoc.Save(ms);
   ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
   fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

FileContentResult file = File(fileBytes, "text/html");
return file;
```

**Problem :** 
    New node ( img ) is not inserting. My footer content gone if i am using this code and if i just read the document from the stream and return as a FileContentResult then everything perfect. I want to know whats the problem with this code or where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTML Agility pack create new HTMLNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309989/html-agility-pack-create-new-htmlnode).

This shows how to properly create a new node.  In  my experience, their code works fine.  Similar to jQuery taking it step by step.  Good luck!

Comment: Namely, you need to use the current node to create a new element.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
HtmlNode usern = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img .... />");
```

to just img

```
HtmlNode usern = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img></img>");
```

and add this

```
 ndoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
```

Comment: @King Kong try this ndoc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

Comment: @King Kong are you using html agility pack to add footer

Comment: no i am using it to add img node , but after inserting the node when i save the document , the footer contents not save or somehow it disappeared. I mentioned this in my question also

Comment: @King Kong try to read the footer content first and the append it after your image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14665/discussion-between-cold-told-and-king-kong)

Comment: @King Kong it might be the way you append the text after the image gets lost

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, resolved it by passing the clone object. 
just modify the line

```
ndoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("id('main')").AppendChild(usern);
```

to

```
ndoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("id('main')").AppendChild(usern.CloneNode(true));
```